# pgo: Where does the schedule of scheduled backups get saved

Tags: postgresql, pgbackrest, crunchy-postgresql-operator

Using Postgres Operator for pgo_create_schedule with the below command:

```
pgo create schedule --schedule="15 10 * * *" --schedule-type=pgbackrest --pgbackrest-backup-type=full mycluster
```

Where the the cron style schedule end up? I dont see it on the server using crontab -l

Answer (score 0):

pgo show schedule 
kubectl -n  get jobs

Answer (score 0):

I found them in the cluster namespace in ConfigMaps called `hippo-pgbackrest-full` and/or `hippo-pgbackrest-diff`.

Replace 'hippo' with your cluster name.